# NoValidConnectionError on Paramiko in Python

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko, scp

```
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
ssh_client.connect(hostname='abc',username='admin',password='admin')
with SCPClient(ssh_client.get_transport()) as scp:
    scp.put(local_path='example.txt',remote_path='/abc')
```

I am trying to connect to a Windows system and send a file `example.txt` to it. But if I run the script, it gives the following error when sending a file to a windows system

> paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 'IP Address'

Help would be appreciated.
Edit: The Windows system that I am sending the file to runs a Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect with Paramiko SSH/SFTP/SCP library to a machine, the machine must be running SSH/SFTP/SCP server.

Windows does not come with SSH/SFTP/SCP server running by default.

See [Windows SSH Servers?](https://superuser.com/q/64058/213663#1191616) question on Super User.